# Safari Blocks Animations on Postback, But FileUpload Cannot Use ASyncPostBackTigger in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, safari, webforms

I'm in a bit of a conundrum here.

I have a `FileUpload` inside an `UpdatePanel`. As `FileUpload` cannot use an `ASnycPostBackTrigger` it must make use of a `PostBackTrigger` kind of defeating the purpose of AJAX (this is a security implementation I assume). Currently when my file upload begins, I show the user a loading gif and when the page posts back it hides the animation.

This works great for all browsers except Safari. Safari freezes all animations during full postback/redirects to save resources (meaning my gif will display but not animate). I am stuck as I am unsure how to render the loading animation as `FileUpload` cannot use partial postback behavior.

Anyone have any ideas on how to render animations during file transfer in Safari?

**UPDATE PANEL**

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="masterPanel">                  
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" /> 
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Submit" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
    OnClientClick="return submitFiles()" />               
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload"  />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**PROGRESS PANEL (HOLDS LOADING ANIMATION**

```html
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="loadingProgess" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatePanel" runat="server">
       <ProgressTemplate>
           <asp:Panel runat="server" id="loading" >
              <div>
                 <asp:Image src="loader.gif" runat="server" ID="loadingImage" />
              </div>
         </asp:Panel>
     </ProgressTemplate>      
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

**SCRIPTS**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">    
        function UploadFile(fileUpload) {
            if (fileUpload.value != '') {
                //Display animation
                document.getElementById('<% Response.Write(loadingProgess.ClientID); %>').style.display = "inline"; 
                //Posts files    
                submitFiles();          
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe a pure css spinner instead of moving gif? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/spinners/. Also you can do async file upload but you'll need to write your own instead of using Webform Controls. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/upload-files-through-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a CSS animation instead of GIF?
[Check this.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

Comment: This ended up being the only option sadly. Not ideal, but at least I can give users loading feedback.